# Can't load module after pip install

Tags: python, pip

I am attempting to use a snapchat module in Python, but the problem I'm having is after I run

```
pip install snapchat
```

... I copy the code to test, and get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./snapchat.py", line 2, in <module>
from snapchat import Snapchat
File "/Users/work/Scripts/snapchat.py", line 2, in <module>
from snapchat import Snapchat
ImportError: cannot import name Snapchat
```

Is this something I'm doing wrong or is it a problem with the package? If I've installed via pip - as I've done with other packages - then surely it should be working?

I'm using Python 2.7.5 on a Mac (default Py. install).

Edit:

Someone noted that my script is the same name as the module. I changed this, but still get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./sc.py", line 2, in <module>
from snapchat import Snapchat
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/snapchat/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
from snapchat.snapchat import Snapchat
ImportError: No module named snapchat
```

Comment: You've named your script with the same name as the module.

Comment: Edited answer. Still reporting a problem even when changing the script name.

Comment: Thanks @matsjoyce. Guess I'll have to write my own package. If you put as answer I will accept.

Comment: @JamesJeffery: you can fork it, fix the import in `__init__.py` and clone that into your project.

Comment: Actually, the `__init__.py` and `setup.py` aren't even on Github. Weird stuff. So your best bet is to take the code and install/package it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the current behaviour is a bug, which has been reported at http://github.com/niothiel/snapchat-python/issues/2. Hopefully it will be fixed soon.